# Blackberry SDK 10 Simulator shortcuts

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I got the simulator installed on my Mac. Not able to find the main screen once i go into some other screen. Is there something like iPhone style button to bring the device back to main screen?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a comprehensive manual: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/637/BlackBerry_Simulator_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

Specifically, you want to look a section titled "Using the BlackBerry device simulator input controls".

Comment: The instructions in the 4.2 manual didn't work. I ended up trying different gestures and swipe from bottom to top worked. Not sure where I can find other gestures. Any ideas?

Comment: This guide is from 2006, this one: http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/develop/simulator/BB10_Device_Simulator_UG.pdf is from 2015